# Editing date and time in events of a series from office365

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm doing an integration of my platform with the Office 365 Calendar through the Microsoft Graph API.

I'm having a problem when I try to change date and hour of a meeting that is part of a series, which has the following payload:

[[image]

I receive the following answer:

[receivePayload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxrY8.png)

[image]

I have tried to add the keys `type` and `seriesMasterId` and it still produces the same error answer. 
Is something wrong with my payload? Can I get some help on how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide more detail about the payload properties.

Comment: sure, what do you need to know?

Comment: Since it says there is a validation error for a field, I would like to see the whole payload object if possible. You can replace your confidential data with dummy names. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the sent payload as you asked to show every key, but my problem is that this works as a single meeting, but if it is part of a series this payload won't work!
Plus, if i don't send the "Start" and "End" key the single occurrence of the series will work, seems is missing something, but I dont know what

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce this issue and it seems like your properties are in the correct format. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Aida for your response.

I have taken this issue to the microsoft team and found out that the trouble had been with creating events in a non-UTC format. I was doing the update with this format and they wouldn't match. I changed it and it solves the issue.